# Reading a file with pandas and use correlation coefficients on two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file like following with no header

```
 0.000000 0.330001 0.280120 
 1.000000 0.355590 0.298581 
 2.000000 0.305945 0.280231
```

I want to read this file using pandas dataframe and want to perform correlation coefficient between the second and the third column.

I am trying like following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('COLVAR_hbondnohead', header=None)
df['1'].corr(df['2'])
```

It pops up with a huge error message. Am I not treating the columns properly? Any suggestion or hint?

Error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 958, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
TypeError: an integer is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sbhakat/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3063, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 164, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
KeyError: '1'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 958, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
TypeError: an integer is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/sbhakat/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2685, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/home/sbhakat/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2692, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "/home/sbhakat/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2486, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "/home/sbhakat/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4115, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "/home/sbhakat/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3065, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 164, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
KeyError: '1'
```

Comment: What is the `huge error message`?

Comment: Are you missing a file extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to specify separator which is space while reading file. Then use position to access the columns. Below code should work.

```
    df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep=' ', header=None)
    df[1].corr(df[2])
```

Comment: Oops yes you are right my mistake. I forgot the separator. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Roy what is the file extension? is it .csv ? if it is you should add it to the end of fileName like pd.read_csv('COLVAR_hbondnohead.csv', header=None)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have columns named `1` and `2`, So, you have to create those columns first.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('COLVAR_hbondnohead', header=None)
df1 = df.reindex(columns=['1','2', '3'])
```

then

```
df1['2'].corr(df1['3'])
```